# Motorola add-ons site get unkown host

Tags: android, motorola-droid

Motorola's Android [Add-on site](http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml) returns with

Blockquote Failed to fetch [URL](http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml/addon.xml)

reason:

```
IO Unknown Host android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com
```

In R21 of the Android SDK Manager Log when added as a User defined site.

1. Do I have the wrong address?
2. Are others having the same issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I get the same, where did you get that address from?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do this manually.

Page where you can download the add ons.

http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html

Instructions on installing:

http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/SDK_Addons/installation.html

Comment: The page you link to just opens a MOTO X marketing site. Nothing to download there.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Well it did work 4 months ago! They've clearly moved it. If you find it again update the post. The instructions are there still so I assume it's still available somewhere.

Comment: You've probably figured this out already, but the site is down permanently.  Motorola decommissioned the developer site and the servers that supported the Eclipse plugins as part of the acquisition.

Comment: So, is Motorola no longer allowing people to develop apps or something? I just wanted to add an AVD to Eclipse for it, but now it doesn't seem possible?

Comment: Motorola have no control over whether people can develop apps for their devices. This was a SDK that let you harness additional features of certain devices, stuff that Android libraries (at the time) didn't cover. I've no idea what, I never actually needed this. I don't think it gave you any special AVD anyway. So I recommend you make an AVD picking specs that match your target device as closely as possible, or just use the real device. I don't bother with virtuals ever.